# Finding a vertical kilometer between 2 points with specified distance in QGIS

Tags: qgis, czech-republic

I'm new to GIS software.
I want to find 2 points in selected area (lets say Czech Republic) with distance 5km or less and altitude difference 1000m or more. 
I know that I can use GMTED datasheet with terrain data but then I'm little bit lost.

If it's a stupid question or it's been answered before, sorry for that.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! You should explain your problem a bit more (maybe some background as to 'why') and what kind of solution you're looking for - there could be an infinite number of points that satisfy your question (if there is any possible solution), so probably you need to define the problem better.

Comment: Why...I want to find out if it's possible to find a vertical kilometer route for skyrunning competition in Czech Republic and this route must be ascending 1000m+ on 5km distance. But it's probably not possible to find exact route so points would be enough and choosing route could be done manually.

You are right with possibility of infinite points. Maybe somehow mark area of these points is the way. Problem is that I can't work with GIS software much so I'm not sure if this problem has a solution or not.

Answer (score 3):

I first had to google what the heck skyrunning is ... ok. So as i understood, the goal is to reach some summit, right?

This is not going to be a highly technical workflow, but a proposal how to get nearer to some solutions.

Would be good if you first select some summits which could serve as destination points to narrow down your areas of interest. I also doubt that there are a lot of possible areas, so best try it only with the 10 highest peaks e.g.

I also think that you are not going to run cross country but need some paths? For this, get some OSM data like http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/czech-republic-latest.shp.zip (480mb file for hole Czech Republic, including a layer for streets and paths etc.)

Then get some elevation data like http://www.gisat.cz/content/en/products/data-download.

Create a point layer, where you digitize your selected summits. For this you could use a WMS-basemap like http://geoportal.cuzk.cz/WMS_ZM50_PUB/WMService.aspx or use the **GeoCode** plugin where you type in the names and it will give you the position in a new point layer.

Give those summits an attribute column with the hight in meters.

Create a 5000m-buffers around the summit points. (Though 5 km linear distance might not be 5km on ground of course)

Next generate 10-meter contour lines from the elevation raster.

Then intersect the contour lines with the buffers.

You then should have a layer with the altitude of the summit and the altitude of the contour line intersected. Calculate a new column on this layer where you substract the summit hight from the contour line hight. Filter those lines with a value lower than 1000 and delete them. Now you see where the remaining contour lines touch the buffers. Together with the paths, you now could select some start point in the vicinity.

This approach is less than elegant and exact, but can give you a quick and dirty overview if there are good areas at all (which I doubt for Czech Republic: Better lower your requirements or change the country ;). And I would do it differently anyway, but that would lead too far for such an answer).

Comment: Thanks for detailed advice. It's exactly what I was looking for.

But unfortunately I stuck with intersecting layers (contour lines with buffers). It always create blank layer and I'm not sure where is mistake.
http://oi57.tinypic.com/4jnma9.jpg

Comment: 1. get yourself acquainted with the processing toolbox. There you find many more functions than in the normal vector menu + it produces only temporary files, which is much better for testing. So when you finally found a way, you save it once to your data folder. 2. try changing the order: intersect the lines WITH the buffers (as i wrote). Hope this works. If not, keep posting questions and results.

Comment: I also see from the screenshot, that your project is in EPSG 4326 (WGS84), which is not metric, but in degrees. Geoprocessing in WGS84 is often not working as expected. Please check the CRS of your buffers and the contour lines. They all should have the same CRS and preferably a metric system (Thats why I posted you the link to the download of the czech DEM already projected in your national grid, normally SRTM data come unprojected in WGS84). So, set your project to your national grid and keep an eye on the CRS produced for all your results, which should have the same CRS!

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Switching order didn't help but converting CRS to World Azimuthal Equidistant with both layers solve the issue. Now I'm going to add much more summits :-)